# Input to the fit method in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm reading the scikit-learn documentation's Type Casting [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#type-casting).

My question is about an ndarray operation which is given as an input to the `fit` method. (Refer the code below)

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> clf = SVC()
>>> clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>>> list(clf.predict(iris.data[:3]))
[0, 0, 0]

>>> clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target_names[iris.target])  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

>>> list(clf.predict(iris.data[:3]))  
['setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa']
```

**Question:** In this part in the code above `clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target_names[iris.target])`, what is the operation performed as `iris.target_names[iris.target]` ?

A few more information:

```
iris.target_names
array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], 
      dtype='|S10')

iris.target
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

iris.target_names[iris.target]
array(['setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa',
   'setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
   'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica',
   'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica'], 
  dtype='|S10')
```

I understand my question is not scikit-learn specific but has something to do with the understanding of numpy operations. I have read the numpy documentation but couldn't figure this out myself. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iris.target` is used as an [index array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) in that operation.

Consider the following array:

```
arr = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
arr
Out: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

At index 0, it has 'a':

```
arr[0]
Out: 'a'
```

At index 0 and 1, it has 'a' and 'b':

```
arr[[0, 1]]
Out: 
array(['a', 'b'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

These indices may have duplicates:

```
arr[[0, 1, 0]]
Out: 
array(['a', 'b', 'a'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

In your example, `iris.target` is an array of encoded labels. To get their names, you use `iris.target` as an index to `iris.target_names` so it gives you the corresponding names for each element.

Comment: Thanks! It was confusing at first as the output array after using the indexing array was larger than the `iris.target_names`.